# Android Cocos2DX using C++ in Eclipse Helios Windows XP

Tags: cocos2d-x, eclipse

I have used Eclipse Helios 3.6.1 for Java development. I wanted to start C++ development in the same IDE so I installed **Autotools Support For CDT, C/C++ Development Tools, C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help plugins**.
I have included **#include "cocos2d.h"** in my **HelloWorldScene.h** file now when writing the below statement
 `cocos2d::CCSprite * ccSprite;` 
I am not getting auto completion bar(template proposals) on writing like coco and pressing **Ctrl + Space** from my keyboard. What can be the problem?
This might help you solve my problem. Please check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmC8a.png). This is what I got after clicking Right Click Project -> Index -> Search for Unresolved Index. But I have added all includes check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujvMs.png). I think this is causing problem in Content Assist. What should I do in this case? Inclusion seems proper.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/686054) The second link under beginner has an indepth explanation of how to set up xcode for iphone and eclipse for android